# ¿Como comparo listas de enteros para saber cual es la mas grande?

Tags: java

Tengo un algoritmo para calcular una secuencia de numeros *(Conjetura de Collatz)*.

El problema es que necesito todas hasta 1,000,000 (un millon), de ahi saber que numero crea la lista mas larga, no se me ocurren buenas ideas pero aunque fuese asi no las puedo implementar en el codigo, entonces como puedo saber cual es la lista mas larga?

Si pueden darme una mano seria de gran ayuda, solo quiero alguna idea, para que yo lo pueda resolver, gracias.

Este es mi codigo:

```
public class Collatz14 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {



    }

    public static void pruebaSecuencia(){

        for (int i = 5; i < 1000000; i++) {

            getSequence(i);
        }


    }


    public static int getSequence(int num){

        Vector secuencia = new Vector(10);

        while(num != 1){  //Algoritmo para obtener la secuencia de numeros

        if(num % 2 == 0){

          num = num/2;  
          secuencia.add(num);

        }

        else if(num % 2 != 0){

            num = (num * 3)+ 1;
            secuencia.add(num);
        }
    }

        return secuencia.size(); //Retorno el tamaño de la secuencia
    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Codigo

```
public class Main {

    public static void iniciarEjercicio(int limite) {

        /* Secuencia Mayor */
        int numeroMayor = 0;
        int cantidadSecuenciaMayor = 0;

        for (int i = 5; i < limite; i++) {

            int cantidadSecuencia = obtenerSecuencia(i);

            if (cantidadSecuencia > cantidadSecuenciaMayor) {
                numeroMayor = i;
                cantidadSecuenciaMayor = cantidadSecuencia;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("El numero que genera mas secuencia es el " + numeroMayor + " con " + cantidadSecuenciaMayor + " secuencias.");

    }

    public static int obtenerSecuencia(int numero) {

        int contador = 0;

        while (numero != 1) {

            contador++;

            if (numero / 2.0 == numero / 2) {
                numero /= 2;
            } else {
                numero = (3 * numero + 1) / 2;
            }
        }

        return contador;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Iniciamos el Programa */
        iniciarEjercicio(1000000);

    }
}
```

---

### Explicación

He modificado un poco tu programa para dejarlo un poco mas sencillo, **no es necesario usar arreglos** ni nada de eso, te lo explicare parte por parte.

#### Primero

Hemos creado la función iniciar `obtenerSecuencia()`, la cual recibe como parámetro un numero y retornara la cantidad de números que se encontraron en esta secuencia.

```
public static int obtenerSecuencia(int numero) {

    int contador = 0;

    while (numero != 1) {

        contador++;

        if (numero / 2.0 == numero / 2) {
            numero /= 2;
        } else {
            numero = (3 * numero + 1) / 2;
        }
    }

    return contador;
}
```

Ves? Solo nos devuelve una variable entera, cuyo valor es la **cantidad de secuencias** encontrara por cada `numero`.

#### Segundo

Hemos creado la función `iniciarEjercicio()` en la cual se especificara el limite hasta el cual correrá nuestro programa. Y a su vez contiene el algoritmo encargado de determinar **cual ha sido el numero que obtuvo mas secuencias**.

```
    public static void iniciarEjercicio(int limite) {

        /* Secuencia Mayor */
        int numeroMayor = 0;
        int cantidadSecuenciaMayor = 0;

        for (int i = 5; i < limite; i++) {

            int cantidadSecuencia = obtenerSecuencia(i);

            if (cantidadSecuencia > cantidadSecuenciaMayor) {
                numeroMayor = i;
                cantidadSecuenciaMayor = cantidadSecuencia;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("El numero que genera mas secuencia es el " + numeroMayor + " con " + cantidadSecuenciaMayor + " secuencias.");

    }
```

---

### [Ejemplo en linea!](https://tio.run/##dVOxboMwEJ2Tr7hmIkEF0qoTpVuGDpUqZaw6OODQS8FObZMqivh2ejaEEpEwGHi883t@d@zYgd3LPRe77Ltp9tWmwBTSgmkNbwwFnKbTSYdqwwzdDhIzQIEpMrXacZXSk/RQGCiwRMPntmQSLmDN04oLotFOR6lgERJueaIquZItmEAUd3DKhMGMZX3dgEGUrVROBQl5ihGeO70Yfb/VvL4L0eXGcMFVD3k4j9uCrTfmv9xwQiJUMrl0j7EDb3offXD82qq7ZX3UhpeBrEywV@S/EN5sVXQRwU/FIbfWGZRMg@49cg28gBn4F2H6hKRSOPyGI0vpt9HBzAVRj5pskxyn1veuzdvFLYVh2aBNv19YcPC6A9wlsJxD250z1ffP4fe0EB6CCJIE/t/nJxjEDWECD110tPBC82E3SN17hMW53Lei4aDARa24qZToHcfu3EDXlfkuafa9taGO5B@fwFSu21PQWL@60S@l68C7krliJXPDPfopllEU2YCtSD2tm@YP)

> *Nota:* El ejemplo en linea se ejecuta solo hasta el numero 1000, debido a que si se ejecuta hasta 1 millon, genera lentitud en el compilador.

#### Resultado

> El numero que genera mas secuencia es el 871 con 113 secuencias.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes guardar los tamaños de los vectores en un Map dentro de la función `pruebaSecuencia()`,

```
Map<Integer, Integer> resultados = new HashMap();

public static void pruebaSecuencia(){
    for (int i = 5; i < 1000000; i++) {
        resultados.add(i, getSequence(i));
    }
}
```

Posteriormente evaluas cual es el mayor.

Otra alternativa con el mismo código que tienes puedes agregar dos variables al inicio y en el método `pruebaSecuencia()` haces la validación:

```
static int numero = 0;
static int tamanioSecuencia = 0;


public static void pruebaSecuencia(){
    for (int i = 5; i < 1000000; i++) {
        int temp = getSequence(i);
        if(temp > tamanioSecuencia){
            tamanioSecuencia = temp;
            numero = i;
        }
     }
 }
```

Después solo imprimes las variables